# 301 Redirection Issue

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect `/test/blog/old-acne-problems` to `samesite/test/blog/acne-being-taken-seriously`

I did the following redirection

```
Redirect 301 /test/blog/old-acne-problems samesite/test/blog/acne-being-taken-seriously
```

but when I checked it the redirection comes out to be

```
samesite/test/blog/acne-being-taken-seriously?q=/test/blog/old-acne-problems
```

an extra query string is coming i.e. `?q`

Please let me know the proper redirection. I don't want `?q=/test/blog/old-acne-problems` this part.

> Note: Redirection is on the same site itself.

Answer (score 0):

- Option 1: You have forgotten the first slash !

  `Redirect 301 /test/blog/old-acne-problems /samesite/test/blog/acne-being-taken-seriously`
- Option 2: There are other rules which change your url. (Probably some rules from wordpress)

*(give us all of your rules)*